# Set Vertices To intersection points [Geometry nodes]

Tags: geometry-nodes

has anyone idea how to set all vertices to intersection points like on image below or slide them to point where them intersect. Thanks [image]

Comment: You mean like an *Auto Merge* feature we have available in *Edit Mode*? I don't think there is a node for that. I think boolean union is the only option for now.

Comment: Do you only connect stripes at 90° and 45°? That would allow to mathematically calculate where the points are supposed to be…

Comment: Yes, It would be helpful.Could You show it in geometry nodes.